# What will be effect of removing sh file in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, sh

i have removed my sh file by mistake. I want to know is it impact on executing a 
    application program? or is it fine? If it effects, then what will be the ways to 
    recover it?

Comment: *What* `.sh` file did you remove? where was it located?

Comment: @JacobVlijm   /bin/sh--- file name which i removed

Comment: @JacobVlijm  sh is simlink to dash. OP removed sh,  not the actual dash. That should be ok, right ?

Comment: @JacobVlijm when i tried to link /bin/sh to /bin/bash by doing the following commands, i got error like "/bin/sh: No such file or directory"

Commands:
sudo rm /bin/sh
sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

Comment: @user3386914 So you've executed them one by one or as one line just like you posted ?

Comment: @Serg Well, it should be fixed! (see Rw.'s answer)

Comment: @JacobVlijm yup, that should do it

Comment: @user3386914 Don't forget to accept the answer!  ;-) If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the abysmally small number *now* turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  **;-)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command to fix this is `cd /bin && sudo ln -s dash /bin/sh`

Comment: shouldn't that be /bin/dash ? full path ?

Comment: I added in a cd otherwise it might fail ;) Full path should not be required.

Comment: Not only are full paths not required, Ubuntu ships with `/bin/sh` as a symbolic link to the relative path `dash`, not the absolute path `/bin/dash`. This can be verified by running `file /bin/sh` or `ls -l /bin/sh` on an Ubuntu system whose `/bin/sh` symlink has not been removed or modified. (Making it link with the absolute path is fine too, but if the goal is to restore it to precisely what it was before, that's simply `dash`.)